# Unity Character controller climbing Terrain

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I'm working on terrain and I made this pit and my character controller acts like 
it is on ground but its floating  for sure and when I move forward it will get dragged down by the gravity but it gets "stuck" again floating  and if I'm on the bottom of the pit and try to climb it it actually climbs the big slop while my slop limit is 45 and it counts like its grounded so I can jump again and yea I tried making a raycast to check if its grounded but still it only fixes the problem with climbing but it still if I jump at the sides of the pit I will start floating.
Here is the script .

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class moveController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private CharacterController controller;
    public float moveSpeed = 15f;
    public float jumpForce = 15f;

    private Vector3 moveDirection;
    private float gravityScale = 0.1f;
    private float up_Down;
    private float right_Left;

    private float mouseX;
    private float mouseY;
    //headbob 
    private float currentAngle = 0;
    private float smooth = 20.0F;
    private float tiltAngle = 1.0F;
    private float tiltAroundZ;
    Vector3 h_bob;
    //AccelerationVariables
    private float jumpVelocityPerSecond = 3f;
    private float speedVelocityPerSecond = 3f;

    // jump or not , moving or not , walking or not,
    private bool isJumping;
    private bool isMoving;
    private bool isWalking;

    // look variables
    Vector2 mouselook;
    Vector2 smoothV;
    private float smoothing = 2f;
    private float sensitivity = 1.5f;

    private Camera eyes;

    private void Awake()
    {
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        eyes = Camera.main;
    }
    void Start()
    {

    }

    void Update()
    {
        Move();
        SlowDown();
        //DeadHop();
      //  MaxSpeed_Jump();
        Crouch();

    }
    private void Move()
    {
        //  moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * moveSpeed, moveDirection.y, Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * moveSpeed);
        up_Down = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        right_Left = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
        mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

        tiltAroundZ = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * tiltAngle;
        currentAngle = Mathf.MoveTowards(currentAngle, tiltAroundZ, Time.deltaTime * smooth);

        Vector3 moveDirSide = transform.right * right_Left * moveSpeed;
        Vector3 moveDirForward = transform.forward * up_Down * moveSpeed ;

        Vector3 BodyRot = transform.rotation.eulerAngles;

        BodyRot.y += mouseX;

        var md = new Vector2(mouseX, mouseY);
        md = Vector2.Scale(md, new Vector2(sensitivity * smoothing, sensitivity * smoothing));
        smoothV.x = Mathf.Lerp(smoothV.x, md.x, 1f / smoothing);
        smoothV.y = Mathf.Lerp(smoothV.y, md.y, 1f / smoothing);
        mouselook += smoothV;
        mouselook.y = Mathf.Clamp(mouselook.y, -80f, 80f);


        // check if he is moving

        if (Input.GetButton("Horizontal"))
        {
            isMoving = true;
        }
        else if (Input.GetButton("Vertical"))
        {
            isMoving = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isMoving = false;
        }


        // check if he is jumping

        if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
        {
            isJumping = true;
        }
        else if (Input.GetButtonUp("Jump"))
        {
            isJumping = false;

        }

        ///check if grounded so he can jump

            if (controller.isGrounded)
           {
            if (isJumping)
            {             
                moveDirection.y = jumpForce;
            }

           }


        moveDirection.y = moveDirection.y + (Physics.gravity.y * gravityScale);

        controller.Move(moveDirSide * Time.deltaTime);
        controller.Move(moveDirForward * Time.deltaTime);
        controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);


        eyes.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(-mouselook.y, Vector3.right.x, -currentAngle);
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(mouselook.x, BodyRot);



    }
a
    private void SlowDown()
    {
        if (Input.GetButton("SlowDown"))
        {
            moveSpeed = 5f;
            jumpForce = 10f;
            isWalking = true;
        }
        else if (Input.GetButtonUp("SlowDown"))
        {
            moveSpeed = 15f;
            jumpForce = 15f;
            isWalking = false;
        }

    }

    //private void DeadHop()
    //{
    //    if (isMoving)
    //    {
    //        jumpForce += jumpVelocityPerSecond * Time.deltaTime ;
    //        moveSpeed += speedVelocityPerSecond * Time.deltaTime ;
    //    }
    //    else if (isMoving == false)
    //    {
    //        jumpForce = 10f;
    //        moveSpeed = 10f;
    //    }
    //}

    //private void MaxSpeed_Jump()
    //{
    //    if(moveSpeed >= 15)
    //    {
    //        moveSpeed = 15;
    //    }
    //    if(jumpForce >= 15)
    //    {
    //        jumpForce = 15;
    //    }
    //}

    private void Crouch()
    {
        if (Input.GetButton("Crouch") && isJumping == false)
        {
            controller.height = 1.5f;
            moveSpeed = 5f;
        }
        else if (Input.GetButtonUp("Crouch") && isJumping == false)
        {
            moveSpeed = 15f;
            controller.height = 3f;
        }


        if (Input.GetButton("Crouch") && isJumping == true)
        {
            controller.height = 1.5f;

        }
        else if (Input.GetButtonUp("Crouch") && isJumping == true)
        {
            moveSpeed = 15f;
            controller.height = 3f;
        }


    }   
}
```

[image]

[image]